# What does "ENG 2 REV PRESSURIZED" ECAM message mean in the Airbus A32F?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-systems

What does "ENG 2 REV PRESSURIZED" ECAM message mean in the A32F (Airbus A320 Freighter)?

What are the possible consequences and actions the crew should take, on ground and during the flight?

Comment: What does the checklist indicate to be the proper course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of Airbus A320 (A318/319/320/321) models, ENG 2 REV PRESSURIZED means that the thrust reverser system is pressurized. From FCOM:

> ENG 1(2) REV PRESSURIZED
>
> Reverser system is pressurized, while rev doors are stowed and locked with no deploy order.

The crew are expected to reduce the engine thrust to idle when possible in flight (also on ground).

> Reverse thrust system is pressurized with reverser doors stowed and locked.
>
> THR LEVER 1 (2) .................................. IDLE
>
> lf flight conditions permit, reduce the thrust of the affected engine to IDLE as a precautionary measure.

You can see a case where [this warning came on](http://avherald.com/h?article=4925087b).

Deployment of thrust reversers in flight could have fatal consequences as seen in a B767 [Lauda Air Flight 004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauda_Air_Flight_004) (note that the warning is about reverser pressurization, not deployment).

Comment: If it were reverser deployment then probably too late to see the warning anyways. :)

Comment: @curious_cat Yes. As an aside, then you'll have a REV UNLOCKED warning probably- though I doubt it'll be of any help.